# C# XML Deserializer Not Deserializing Date

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I'm having trouble with `XML` deserialization in `C#`.
I have the following `XML`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<head>
  <person>
    <name>Jim Bob</name>
    <dateOfBirth>1990-01-01</dateOfBirth>
  </person>
  <policy>
    <number>1</number>
    <pet>
      <name>Snuffles</name>
      <dateOfBirth>2000-01-01</dateOfBirth>
    </pet>
  </policy>
</head>
```

With this I'm trying to map it to the following classes:

```
public class head
{
    public policy policy { get; set; }
    public person person { get; set; }
}

public class person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("policy")]
    public List<policy> policy { get; set; }
}

public class policy
{
    public string number { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("pet")]
    public List<pet> pet { get; set; }
}

public class pet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dateOfBirth")]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; } //<~~ Issue is with this property
}
```

The issue is that the `dateOfBirth` property in the `pet` class isn't being populated when being deserialized and I don't know why. Is this because of a naming conflict with the `dateOfBirth` property in the `person` class?

Comment: Should your `head` class contain a `policy` property?

Comment: The problems are that 1) You are missing `public policy policy { get; set; }` on `head` and 2) `[XmlElememnt("dateOfBirth")]` is misspelled and does not compile.  Fixing those your code works, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5veH6q

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I've updated the question as that was a quickly typed example of the issue. I've rectified the typo / missing property as they are present in the full code.

Comment: OK, but now I can't reproduce the problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/5veH6q.  `<dateOfBirth>2000-01-01</dateOfBirth>` seems to populate successfully.

Comment: @dbc Ok thanks, I've ran my full code through the same fiddle and I'm getting the same error. You've answered my question anyway that it's not a naming conflict. I'll keep picking away at it! Thanks

Comment: Datetime is expecting the date and time combination but in your xml it contains only the date part like 2000-01-01 and the time part is missing. So you have to parse the string to datetime manually

Comment: @Hassaan : That doesn't make any sense.  The issue is a DateTime cannot be null.

Comment: @Gareth, seems to populate correctly for me. can you show us the code you use to deserialize the xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using the `[XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]` attribute on the `dateOfBirth` field . The revised class that works looks like this:

```
public class pet
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code which uses ParseExact.  If you are still getting an issue you may have to handle cases where the DateTime is null :

```
    public class pet
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth { get; set; } //<~~ Issue is with this property

        [XmlElement("dateOfBirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); }
            set { _dateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }
        }


    }
```